# Storing form responses in session data

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am working with a some multi stage forms in my Scala Play application at the moment, the end result of this multi step form is to send a POST request to an end point with this JSON structure,

`{{ "name":"Company Name", "contact": { "firstname":"Firstname1", "surname":"Surname1", "email":"firstname1.surname1@xyz.com", "textPhone":false, "phone":"12222222222222" }, "address": { "addressLine1":"Address Line 1", "town":"Town1", "county":"County", "postcode":"LS1 3DE" }
}`

For each form submission I am doing the following,

```
request.session + ("organisation_name" -> formData.toString())
```

Is there away that I can have this JSON structure in a session and push the data to the correct attributes? Or is there a way that I can take the session data and manipulate it into JSON that follows the above format?

Answer (score 0):

One way to add something to a session is like this:

```
request.session.copy(
  data = request.session.data + ("organisation_name" -> formData.toString())
)
```

Another way to add to a session at the return point is like this:

```
Redirect(routes.......).addingToSession("organisation_name" -> formData.toString())
```

Answer (score -1):

Have tried Storing your JSON object in request session.
Or u can try caching the JSON object with the Timestamp then read it from cache map so when u go back to the previous from u can Repopululate by getting its attributes.

Comment: Storing the JSON object in to request session would work, if I could get it to compile.